# Does C++ have a sequential search function?

Tags: c++, search

I have a small unsorted array and I'd like to find the **index** of a particular value.  Does C++ have a built-in sequential search function for this, or do you just write the loop yourself each time it comes up?

I'm specifically using a C-style array like:

```
std::string arr[5] = { "EVEN", "ODD", "NONE", "MARK", "SPACE" };
```

and I need the index of a value that the user supplies.

Comment: Which array do you mean? type[size]?

Comment: std::string array[5] for one typical example among about half a dozen that I need to use it for.

Comment: I see. That's exactly what I meant. Will you please edit the question to clarify that you mean C-style arrays and not just STL containers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::find()` should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using std::string;

std::string arr[5] = { "EVEN", "ODD", "NONE", "MARK", "SPACE" };


int main() {

    string* pArrEnd = arr + sizeof( arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    string* pFound = std::find( arr, pArrEnd, "MARK");

    if (pFound == pArrEnd) {
        printf( "not found\n");
    }
    else {
        printf( "%s was found at index %d\n", pFound->c_str(), pFound - arr);
        printf( "or using STL: %d\n", std::distance( arr, pFound));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With C++11 you can use `auto pArrEnd = std::end(arr);` from `<iterator>`. Much nicer! ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Use [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from the STL-*algorithm*-library, or the `find()`-method of your particular container.

Comment: Thanks. I feel silly for asking, but I can write the function faster than I was finding it by searching for "C++ sequential search".

Comment: BTW, you can use std::find on containers other than just STL containers.  For example, a simple C-style array can be searched using std::find()

Comment: @sharptooth: all STL iterators are designed such that they have the same semantics as pointers.  thus a pointer is an iterator, for STL purposes :)

Comment: @sharptooth: std::find(the_array, the_array + num_elements, the_value)

Comment: @sharptooth: The linked page has a nice example using each an array and a vector.

Comment: Looks like Michael Burr has already posted one. Now it's clear. Though it's not so obvious without an example.

Comment: Sorry, I had to unaccept this answer. That function returns a pointer to the array element, and I need the index.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Subtract `arr` to get the index.

Comment: You can quite easily calculate the index from the pointer ((result - array) / sizeof(*array))

Comment: @sikx: no need to divide by sizeof(*array). result - array will give proper value.

Comment: if you use find, i believe youshould do   find(a, a + n, string("haha")); i'm not sure but if it is a dumb implementation and you just pass "haha", it will take it as a char const* . and will construct a temporary std::string each time it compares. not so when you pass in a std::string directly

Comment: @litb: no it won't construct every time. find is not a macro.

Answer (score 5):

You can use STL algos on containers other than just STL containers.  For example, you can std::find() in a C-style array:

```
// alloc the array
static const size_t numItems = 100000;
int * items = new int[numItems];

// fill the array
for( size_t n = 0; n < numItems; ++n )
    items[n] = n;

// find 42 using std::find()
int* found = std::find(&items[0], &items[numItems], 42);
if( found == &items[numItems] )
{
    // this is one past the end, so 42 was not found
    items[0] = 42;
}
else
{
    // we found the first instance of 42 at this location
    // change it to 43
    *found = 43;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you also be able to just use the name of the array rather than `&array[0]`?

Comment: Sure.  I just prefer &array[0] because it seems semantically a little more clear to me.  Just a style thing.

Comment: @warren: semantically &array[0] is the address of the first element, while array is just the array that is implicitly converted to the same pointer. John is just making explicit in the code what the compiler would make implicitly in your case.

Comment: please note that &items[numItems] is undefined behavior (although it will work in most cases for reasons &*(int*)0 will work too in most cases). i would prefer items + numItems instead, which is valid. (and items + 0 for the other side for symmetric reasons then, indeed :))

Comment: @litb: I think it is undefined behavior only if you try to dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you need the index and not the iterator.

```
int main()
{
    // for c++ vector
    typedef int Element;
    typedef std::vector<Element> CppVector;

    CppVector v;
    v.push_back( 2 );
    v.push_back( 4 );
    v.push_back( 8 );
    v.push_back( 6 );

    const Element el = 4;

    CppVector::const_iterator it = std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), el );
    if ( it == v.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "there is no such element" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        const CppVector::size_type index = it - v.begin();
        std::cout << "index = " << index << std::endl;
    }

    // for C array
    typedef Element CVector[4];
    CVector cv;
    cv[0] = 2;
    cv[1] = 4;
    cv[2] = 8;
    cv[3] = 6;

    const std::size_t cvSize = sizeof( cv ) / sizeof( Element );

    std::cout << "c vector size = " << cvSize << std::endl;

    const Element* cit = std::find( cv, cv + cvSize, el );
    const std::size_t index = cit - cv;

    if ( index >= cvSize )
        std::cout << "there is no such element" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "index = " << index << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's better to store the difference of two pointers in ptrdiff_t type, it can be negative (not in your case, but in general).

Comment: then comparison with => cvSize will issue warning.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the STL possibility (`std::find`) already mentioned there is the POSIX function `lsearch` (with c semantics).